# In which EU countries it is illegal to carry/have a kubotan keyring at customs?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, legal, hand-luggage

I had the situation in the past when I had a plastic [kubotan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kubotan) key ring at the security checks at the airport in the UK, so one of the officer called the police and it was confiscated and I've received the warning. But it could end up with the worst case scenario.

Therefore in which countries it is illegal to carry/have a kubotan at customs for self-defense? Or where I can check where it's illegal to avoid similar situations in the future?

E.g. UK laws says:

- [Knives: the laws on buying and carrying](https://www.gov.uk/find-out-if-i-can-buy-or-carry-a-knife) at gov.uk

  > There is a ban on the sale of some knives:
  >
  > - hollow kubotan (cylinder-shaped keychain) holding spikes

But mine did not contain any spikes.

[image: Kubotan]

Comment: I would believe everybody will consider it as being used as arms and will confiscate it. Generally all arms are prohibited in cabin baggage. And I believe all knifes larger than 6cms are prohibited in cabin baggage. Might go through in checked baggage, but it is a big `if`.

Comment: Somebody said e.g.: `Actually the policeman is wrong it is legal to carry a kubotan as long as its on a key chain.`, or `Kubatons are legal to carry.`, source: [Re: Kubotan law in UK](https://www.stormfront.org/forum/t342462-2/). It's true?

Comment: THere is difference between carrying inside the UK and carrying it on a plane with you. Sikhs in UK are allowed to carry their `kirpans` inside UK, but they aren't allowed on planes. http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/33884/are-there-any-flights-which-permits-a-sikh-to-carry-a-kirpan

Comment: I think this is too broad, asking for a list of countries. I suggest focusing on one (or maybe a small list) of countries you actually plan to visit.

Comment: Made the focus on EU.

Comment: @kenorb: Still pretty broad, but perhaps narrow enough. We'll see what the community says :)

Comment: Were you trying to enter the UK (i.e. customs) or to board a plane?

Comment: @Relaxed: Board a plane. Is there any difference when I'm crossing the border instead?

Comment: You ought to clarify your question. Rules for air travel are (mostly?) unified across Europe and much more restrictive than laws about what you can have in each country (which do differ). Laws about what you can carry or buy in the UK aren't relevant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All kinds of weapons, small or big, cold or fire, whether used for self defense or mass destruction are **strictly prohibited** onboard all flights, all airlines, in all countries and airports.

If you managed to get it onboard a flight, then it must be due to improper security check at the gate, not because they allow it. From the [TSA's](http://www.tsa.gov/traveler-information/prohibited-items) page on prohibited items onboard:

> Item -------- **Carry-on?** ---------- Checked? 
>   Kubatons -------**NO** ----------------- OK

And from the [European Commission](http://ec.europa.eu/transport/modes/air/security/doc/info_travellers_hand_luggage.pdf) on the same subject:

> c. objects with a sharp point or sharp edge (objects with a sharp point or sharp edge
>   capable of being used to cause serious injury)...
>   e. e. blunt instruments (objects capable of being used to cause serious injury when used to hit)...

Also, another interesting note in the [official UK page](https://www.gov.uk/hand-luggage-restrictions/overview)

> Airport security staff won’t let anything through that they consider dangerous - even if it’s normally allowed in hand luggage.

And in [another official UK page](http://www.nidirect.gov.uk/index/information-and-services/travel-transport-and-roads/public-transport/air-travel/dangerous-and-restricted-items-what-you-cannot-take-on-board-a-flight.htm):

> You can't take any objects in your hand baggage that could cause injury to yourself and other passengers. You may be able to take some of these items in your hold baggage (the luggage you check in) instead.

Just open any official hand luggage restriction page, and you will find the same thing. In short, any object, whether it is called a weapon or not, that can be used to attack people and cause harm to others is prohibited once it is spotted. To be in the safe side and to avoid confiscation or even worse actions, put it in the checked in luggage.

Comment: I start writing the answer before you change the question to cover EU only, so I am keeping other quotes from other countries.

Comment: Sure, the info for other countries would be useful as well.