# Travelling to Izmir, Turkey, as a Sikh

Tags: safety, planning, turkey, religion

As a Sikh who wears a turban as a part of my religion, should I have safety concerns or take precautions in order to travel to Turkey? Are there other things I need to think about while being there, as an Indian Sikh?

Comment: Please see [this question](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/33884/are-there-any-flights-which-permits-a-sikh-to-carry-a-kirpan) regarding carrying a kirpan.

Comment: Is this question only about Turkey, or about all countries in between departing from India? Please [edit] your question to make that clear.

Answer (score 8):

You don't need to worry about anything in Turkey. I have visited Turkey thrice and have seen many Sikhs with Turban. Turkey is well modernized to my belief and is open to tourists from all cultural backgrounds and religions.

Answer (score 8):

Local here.

99.8% of the population identified as Muslim, [according to wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Islam_in_Turkey), so your turban won't be a problem *anywhere* in Turkey, especially in Izmir. It is one of the most modern city in Turkey and people are really respectful in there *no matter* what religion you have and what you wear.

You should *not* concern about this.

Comment: I don't follow the logic of your post. Why does 98% of the population of Turkey being Muslim mean that being visibly identifiable as a Sikh won't be a problem? I imagine that the asker is worried precisely _because_ Turkey is so religiously homogeneous and they are identifiably different.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Ouch, sorry about that. I was misunderstood. I thought OP _is_ worried about wearing his turban might be a problem because of the majority of the Muslim population which is irrelevant as you said.

Answer (score 4):

In your case, I don't think there will be any problem. The Turkish neither know much about the Sikhs nor they care about them, to be honest. So even if you went to the most religious and intolerant parts of the Turkey -I come from one of those parts- I would doubt that you would encounter any reaction.

However, going to any place in Turkey with a clothing that made a serious statement for Christianity or against Islam would not be the wisest choice. Especially these days secularism and tolerance to other cultures are not the most cherished principles. Though even in that case, I would not think anything more serious than nasty looks and verbal attack is likely in general.